# why i am i getting the error: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Tags: python, function, authentication, user-defined-functions, attributeerror

I am creating a login system that asks a user for a username and password when registering. I used a function for checking to see if the username was valid, then to see if the password was valid according to the requirements.(username could not already be in use and must contain letters)(password must contain capitals, lower-case and numbers). the username function works perfectly, but for some reason in the password function I receive the error: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'isdigit' Does anyone know what I am doing differently between the two functions that makes one functional and the other not. Thanks.

```
    def Username(user_name):
    user_names = open('Username list.txt', 'r+')
    uname_list = user_names.readlines()
    char_user = [user_name]
    for i in range(len(uname_list)):
        uname_list[i] = uname_list[i].strip('\n')
    for i in range(len(uname_list)):
        if uname_list[i] == user_name:
            return 'username already taken'
    for i in range(len(char_user)):
        if char_user[i].isspace() == True:
            return 'username cannot contain spaces' 
    if user_name.isdigit() == True:
        return 'username must contain letters'
    elif len(user_name) < 4 or len(user_name) > 12:
        return 'username must be between 4 and 12 characters'
    else:
        user_names.write(str(user_name + '\n'))
        file.close(user_names)
        return True

def Password(password, p2):
    passwords = open('Password list.txt', 'r+')
    if password != p2:
        return 'you did not enter the same password twice'
    elif password.isdigit() == True:
        return 'username must contain letters'
    elif password.islower() == True:
        return 'username must contain a capital letter'
    elif password.isupper() == True:
        return 'username must contain a lower case letter' 
    elif password.isalpha() == True:
        return 'username must contain a number'
    elif len(user_name) < 4 or len(user_name) > 12:
        return 'username must be between 4 and 12 characters'
    else:
        passwords.write(str(password + '\n'))
        return True 


print 'What would you like your username to be?'        
print  'Your username must be between 4 and 12 characters, contain letters and not contain any spaces'
user_name = raw_input()
valid = Username(user_name)
while valid != True:
    print valid
    user_name = raw_input()
    valid = Username(user_name)

print 'enter your password twice below for validication'
password = raw_input()
password2 = raw_input()
valid = Password(password,password2)
while valid != True:
    print valid
    print 'enter your password twice below'
    password = raw_input
    password2 = raw_input
    valid = Password(password,password2)
```

What happens when program is run.

```
    '''What would you like your username to be?
    Your username must be between 4 and 12 characters, contain letters and not contain any spaces
    Test
    enter your password twice below for validication
    Your password must include capital letters, lowercase letters, numbers and be betweeen 4 and 12 characters
    testing
    testing
    username must contain a capital letter
    enter your password twice below
    AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'isdigit'''
```

Comment: Just wondering what i did that made this a negatively voted question? Does anyone have any suggestions for future questions

Comment: Posting the full traceback would be a good start, as would explaining what you've tried so far to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You only reverence `raw_input` but don't call it in the last two lines.

Your Password-check is buggy. All Lower + digit or All upper + digit are valid passwords.

Comment: enter your password twice below for validication
1234adsf
1234adsf
username must contain a capital letter
enter your password twice below
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Comment: enter your password twice below for validication
ABCD1224
ABCD1224
username must contain a lower case letter
enter your password twice below
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Comment: @JDizzle98 read the first line of the answer to solve the error, and the second to fix your logic bug.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function, you need parentheses `()` around it:

```
>>> password = raw_input
>>> password.isdigit() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
>>> password = raw_input()
67
>>> password.isdigit()
True
>>>
```

Here is your updated code:

```
def Username(user_name):
    user_names = open('Username list.txt', 'r+')
    uname_list = user_names.readlines()
    char_user = [user_name]
    for i in range(len(uname_list)):
        uname_list[i] = uname_list[i].strip('\n')
    for i in range(len(uname_list)):
        if uname_list[i] == user_name:
            return 'username already taken'
    for i in range(len(char_user)):
        if char_user[i].isspace() == True:
            return 'username cannot contain spaces' 
    if user_name.isdigit() == True:
        return 'username must contain letters'
    elif len(user_name) < 4 or len(user_name) > 12:
        return 'username must be between 4 and 12 characters'
    else:
        user_names.write(str(user_name + '\n'))
        file.close(user_names)
        return True

def Password(password, p2):
    passwords = open('Password list.txt', 'r+')
    if password != p2:
        return 'you did not enter the same password twice'
    elif password.isdigit() == True:
        return 'username must contain letters'
    elif password.islower() == True:
        return 'username must contain a capital letter'
    elif password.isupper() == True:
        return 'username must contain a lower case letter' 
    elif password.isalpha() == True:
        return 'username must contain a number'
    elif len(user_name) < 4 or len(user_name) > 12:
        return 'username must be between 4 and 12 characters'
    else:
        passwords.write(str(password + '\n'))
        return True 


print 'What would you like your username to be?'        
print  'Your username must be between 4 and 12 characters, contain letters and not contain any spaces'
user_name = raw_input()
valid = Username(user_name)
while valid != True:
    print valid
    user_name = raw_input()
    valid = Username(user_name)

print 'enter your password twice below for validication'
password = raw_input()
password2 = raw_input()
valid = Password(password,password2)
while valid != True:
    print valid
    print 'enter your password twice below'
    password = raw_input()
    password2 = raw_input()
    valid = Password(password,password2)
```

In the middle of your file you correctly call `raw_input()`, but you forget at the end. Simple python mistake, almost as common as using `==` instead of `=` or the other way around :)